# Translation of a Point

Tags: vector-spaces

This may be a stupid question, but if you take a point, and rotate it / reflect it / translate it, is it always possible to trace a vector from the starting point to the finish point? My teacher said that I was wrong, but I don't think I am.

Comment: It is always possible to trace a vector from any point to any other point, no matter how they were built in the first place.

Comment: The context of the question is not very clear though, so maybe there are some premises that are missing and that are the reason your teacher said you were wrong.